# How to orbit an object at certain speed in Unity?

Tags: unity

I want to move an object around a circle. So I have this code below:

```
    static public int theta = 0;

void Update(){

    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;

    position.x = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Cos (theta) * Time.deltaTime;
    position.y = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Sin (theta) * Time.deltaTime;
    this.transform.position = position;
    theta += 1;
}
```

The object orbits, but it orbits so fast!!! I want the object to rotate like 1 orbit per second only.  How to do that?

ANSWER TO THIS PROBLEM, THANKS!

```
static public int theta = 0;

void Update(){

    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;

    position.x = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Cos (theta) * Time.deltaTime;
    position.y = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Sin (theta) * Time.deltaTime;
    this.transform.position = position;
    theta += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using FixedUpdate instead of Update method?
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Comment: yup, same results

Comment: There is a method to rotate elements, take a look at this post:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/595467/controlling-the-rotation-speed-of-an-object.html

Comment: the rotate element if you want to rotate an object by its own origin.  But what I want to happen is to rotate object A along the circumference of object B.

Comment: The probably the rotateAround method:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rotate-an-object-around-another-object.59289/

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
                position.x = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Cos (theta * Mathf.PI);
  position.y = 0 + 50 * Mathf.Sin (theta * Mathf.PI);
  this.transform.position = position;
  theta += Time.deltaTime;

Still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, theta was declared as float and updated the values as well to (theta * Mathf.PI * speed)... still it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case I am pretty sure the problem lies elsewhere - if slowing the rotation speed 100 times did not have any effect. Aren't you perhaps manipulating either theta or position somewhere else in code?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by changing theta += 1 to theta += 1 * Time.deltaTime; it works fine now.

Comment: If this solves your problem post your solution as an answer

Comment: Just a note: 1 * Time.deltaTime; is redundant multiplying it by 1 results in the same number.  theta += Time.deltaTime; is fine. ...so it worked after all, right? You just forgot +=1 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this...

```
public float orbitsPerSecond = 1f;
public float orbitRadius = 1f;

// Current angle in radians.
float orbitAngle;

void Update(){
    orbitAngle += Time.deltaTime * Mathf.PI * 2f * orbitsPerSecond;

    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;

    position.x = 0 + orbitRadius * Mathf.Cos (orbitAngle);
    position.y = 0 + orbitRadius * Mathf.Sin (orbitAngle);
    this.transform.position = position;
}
```

What I changed:

- I added public parameters so you can change the radius and speed of the orbit in the Inspector.
- I renamed your theta variable orbitAngle and made it an instance member float, so it can hold fractional values and isn't shared across all copies of this script (Even if you need them to sync, you'll want to make sure they're not all increasing this value!)
- I moved the update of orbitAngle to the top of update, and included orbitsPerSecond and Time.deltaTime so it advances at a controlled rate each frame.
- I removed Time.deltaTime from the equations for x and y. Putting it there, it would have caused your orbit radius to shrink when at a high framerate, and grow or jitter when your framerate drops, which isn't a behaviour you'd said you wanted.